# Missing ipmi Device (Remote Access Card) / ipmitool Failue: Could not open device at /dev/ipmi0 ... No such file or directory

Tags: server, hp, devices, ipmi

I recently bought second-hand a [HP Proliant N36L Microserver](https://www8.hp.com/nz/en/pdf/HP_ProLiant_MicroServer_tcm_194_1127013.pdf), and I'm having trouble configuring it for remote access on Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS.

It came with a HP Remote Access card, but when I try to access its web server (following [this setup guide](http://www.livingonthecloud.net/2011/08/hp-microserver-remote-access-card.html)) and enter the default credentials ("admin" / "password"), the credentials are incorrect.

The remote access card [user manual](http://h20628.www2.hp.com/km-ext/kmcsdirect/emr_na-c02948881-3.pdf) (page 63) gives a method to reset the credentials:

> Under Linux shell:
>     Get the user name:
>       `ipmitool raw 0x6 0x46 0x02` (the value “2” is the User ID) 
>     Set user password:
>       `ipmitool raw 0x6 0x47 0x02 0x02` + `password` (Password is ASCI value: 16 bytes)

The problem I have is that when I try and run the `ipmitool` command, I am presented with the following error message:
`Could not open device at /dev/ipmi0 or /dev/ipmi/0 or /dev/ipmidev/0: No such file or directory`

There is a similar [known issue](https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?cc=bo&docId=emr_na-c01930307&lang=es-bo) in that additional *"Configuration Required for IPMITOOL Management Utility to Function on any HP ProLiant Server With an Integrated Lights-Out 2 (iLO 2) and Running Ubuntu Linux 9.04 Server"*

It states you need to load the following modules with the following commands:

```
modprobe ipmi_msghandler
modprobe ipmi_devintf
modprobe ipmi_si
```

... which I have done, to get `ipmitool` to work.

I've also added them to the `/etc/modules` files so they load during boot.

When I run `lsmod | grep ipmi`, I get the following:

```
ipmi_devintf           65536  0
ipmi_si                20480  0
ipmi_msghandler       106496  2 ipmi_devintf,ipmi_si
```

so clearly the modules have been loaded and are running... right?

From what I understand, in Ubuntu, the `ipmi` service/daemon starts automatically when these commands are run.

Despite all this, even when I run the `ipmitool` command without any arguments, it fails with the main `Could not open device at`... error.

Why isn't the /dev/ipim0 device being created automatically?
Do I need to create the /dev/ipim0 device manually?

I did try to create the device manually following [this guide](https://forum.likg.org.ua/ipmi/create-dev-ipmi0-device-manually-t355.html) but even afterwards the `ipmitool` command still gave the same error.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem ... just recently ;)
Just tried to follow the way to add some paraemeters to the kernel so that the address of the device is correct ... ( if I understand well )

Found this solution via link : http://bodgitandscarper.co.uk/tag/microserver/ look at one of the topics. He found the answer to his problem at http://patgardner.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/hp-microserver-remote-management-card.html ...

Adding the parameters "ipmi_si.type=kcs ipmi_si.ports=0xca2" to the kernel startup command in grub did the trick for me in Ubuntu 18 lts.

After reboot:
sudo ipmitool chassis status 
--> worked
sudo ipmitool raw 0x6 0x46 0x02
--> worked

Hope this helps you,
Greetings
Jan.